# MFA is needed starting Nov 12, 2023

Tags: api, user, mfa, okta

On the 12th of November we will only be able to access Salesforce by confirming the verification through MFA, in our case we are doing it through Okta.

We have a total of 149 users, of which 136 are Salesforce user licenses, I understand that this deployment only affects these users, correct?

On the other hand, of these 136 Salesforce license users, two have integration profile between Salesforce and SAP, and Salesforce and Magento, means, there is no browser access, I understand that in this case these two users aren't affected either, correct?

In conclusion, the rollout of MFA affects in the case of our org to 134 Salesforce license users, which are already accessing for months through Okta.

I hope I have explained myself and that the questions I have asked will be answered.

Thank you very much for your help.

Mónica Martínez

Comment: Have you checked the [MFA discussion group](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/groups/0F93A000000DQQHSA4?tab=discussion&sort=LAST_MODIFIED_DATE_DESC) and also the [MFA Trailhead](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/quick-start-turn-on-multi-factor-authentication)?

Answer (score 1):

MFA is only required for UI logins. Integrations and API logins remain unaffected. In other words, your understanding of the situation is correct.